# Maintaining quotes in read_csv in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file with one column whose data contains quotes (i.e. the column is `address` and a typical data point would be `"3rd District, Silver Spring"`. When I do `df = read_csv(file)`, in the dataframe the value appears as `3rd District, Silver Spring` without the quotes. Is there a way to coerce `read_csv` to include the quotes in the dataframe itself? I've tried using the `quoting` parameter but it doesn't seem to change anything. Thanks!

Comment: No, why would you want it? That seems pointless.

Comment: I somewhat agree with cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, but would doing something like `df['address'].apply(lambda x: '"'+x+'"')` be a viable option after the load?

Comment: Can we kindly ask why you need to retain quotes? Such values will be  considered string objects.

Comment: Note: The quotes are added to the CSV as the cell contains a comma. When the data does not contain a comma, the cell can optionally omit the quotes. If you were to write the data (without quotes) back to the file, the quotes would automatically be added back if there are still commas present.